# “Regression to the mean” versus serial correlation

Tags: autocorrelation

“Regression to the mean” says that higher pre-test values will have lower post-test values (and vice versa). This phenomenon will decrease the correlation between the pre- and post-values. However, pre- and post-test values are always serially correlated. How can this be?

Comment: By "decrease" do you mean "make correlation negative" or do you mean "shrink the magnitude of correlation toward zero?"

Comment: @Alexis: I mean “shrink the magnitude of correlation towards zero”.

Comment: Ok, but regression to the mean does not imply a correlation that shrinks towards zero, but negative correlation (i.e. exceptionally high measures at time $t$ are likely to be followed by lower measures at $t+1$, whereas exceptionally low measures at time $t$ are likely to be followed by higher measures at time $t+1$.

Comment: It might shed some light on this question to formulate the concept of regression to the mean correctly.  It does not assert that "higher pretest values will have lower post-test values," because it is always possible for higher pretest values to have even greater post-test values. Moreover, it's not some kind of causal "phenomenon" that changes the numbers!  It's purely a mathematical description of a correlation analysis of any bivariate dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Its interesting to bring up the relationship between regression to the mean and autocorrelation, but you  miss something important about autocorrelation. For observations $t=2$, such as apre-test-post-test design, the lag-1 autocorrelation coefficient, $r_k=-0.5$, invariably. Nonetheless, there may be some relationship between the two in an abstract sense.

*Edit*

In response to your question, here is a simple way to think about it.

The formula for autocorrelation is

$$\frac{\sum_{t=L+1}^T(x_t-\bar{x})(x_{t-1}-\bar{x})}{\sum_{t=1}^T(x_t-\bar{x})^2}$$

Thus, in a pre-test-post-test design with number of observations $T=2$, the only meaningful lag is $L=1$, so the formula for autocorrelation becomes

$$\frac{(x_2-\bar{x})(x_1-\bar{x})}{(x_1-\bar{x})^2+(x_2-\bar{x})^2}$$

Convince yourself that this expands to

$$\frac{(x_1-\bar{x})(x_2-\bar{x})}{2\bar{x}^2-2x_1\bar{x}-2x_2\bar{x}+x_1^2+x_2^2}$$

Remember now that $\bar{x}$ is $(x_1+x_2)/2$. Therefore,

$$\frac{(x_1-\frac{x1+x2}{2})(x2-\frac{x1+x2}{2})}{2(\frac{x1+x2}{2})^2-2x_1(\frac{x1+x2}{2})-2x_2(\frac{x1+x2}{2})+x_1^2+x_2^2}=\frac{(\frac{x_1-x_2}{2})(\frac{x_2-x_1}{2})}{\frac{(x_1-x_2)^2}{2}}=\frac{x_1-x_2}{2(x_2-x_1}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Why is it that “Negative autocorrelation seems to appear less frequently than positive autocorrelation. (http://www.pmean.com/09/NegativeAutocorrelation.html)” but autocorrelation is always -0.5 for t =2? Could you give me some references? Thank you.

Comment: KuJ, you confound *estimates* with the actuality.  This formula, which is an *estimator,* of course works poorly with only two observations, and its value should not be confused with the true underlying correlation. (It's not even relevant to regression generally: it's a time series estimator.)  I'm afraid this confounding seems to be present in the answer, too, so we should be very clear about this: in your question by "always serially correlated" do you mean correlation *estimates* are always nonzero or that *actual correlations* are nonzero?  (Neither can be universally true, btw.)